# Error Processing Request: Error in file: - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Hi have this error in Magento. Either front or back end have this error.

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 709143053158

And when I get the logs, here is what I have:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:227:
"Error in file: "/home/vetement/public_html/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Cartalert/sql/adjcartalert_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php"
- SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mage_adjcartalert' already exists"
;i:1;s:964:"
#0 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '3.2.0')
#2 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('3.2.0')
#3 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/vetement/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/vetement/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}"
;s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Now, can anyone help me resolve this issue.

I have logged into PHPMyAdmin, but hate to play in database.

Not sure if I should drop the mage_adjcartalert table.

Here is what I get on the website :

```
    PDOException Object
    (
        [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mage_adjcartalert' already exists
        [string:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 42S01
        [file:protected] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
        [line:protected] => 228
        [trace:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
                        [line] => 228
                        [function] => execute
                        [class] => PDOStatement
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 110
                        [function] => _execute
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                        [line] => 300
                        [function] => _execute
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
                        [line] => 479
                        [function] => execute
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Statement
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
                        [line] => 238
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 419
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 340
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
                            )

                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 608
                        [function] => raw_query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8
                            )

                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 590
                        [function] => multi_query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO mage_core_config_data (`scope` , `scope_id` , `path` , `value` )
        VALUES ('default', '0', 'catalog/adjcartalert/from_date', '2013-12-08 23:38:05');

                            )

                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 933
                        [function] => multiQuery
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO mage_core_config_data (`scope` , `scope_id` , `path` , `value` )
        VALUES ('default', '0', 'catalog/adjcartalert/from_date', '2013-12-08 23:38:05');

                            )

                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Cartalert/sql/adjcartalert_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
                        [line] => 33
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;
    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert (
      `cartalert_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `is_preprocessed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `products` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`cartalert_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO mage_core_config_data (`scope` , `scope_id` , `path` , `value` )
        VALUES ('default', '0', 'catalog/adjcartalert/from_date', '2013-12-08 23:38:05');

                            )

                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 624
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Cartalert/sql/adjcartalert_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
                            )

                        [function] => include
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 421
                        [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => install
                                [1] => 
                                [2] => 3.2.0
                            )

                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 327
                        [function] => _installResourceDb
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 3.2.0
                            )

                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 235
                        [function] => applyUpdates
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [15] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                        [line] => 417
                        [function] => applyAllUpdates
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ::
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                        [line] => 343
                        [function] => _initModules
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/Mage.php
                        [line] => 683
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [scope_code] => 
                                        [scope_type] => store
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/index.php
                        [line] => 87
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage
                        [type] => ::
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => store
                            )

                    )

            )

        [errorInfo] => Array
            (
                [0] => 42S01
                [1] => 1050
                [2] => Table 'mage_adjcartalert' already exists
            )

    )
```

As stated in the comments below, dropped all the tables, and now this is what I get

```
        PDOException Object
    (
        [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vetement_mage2.mage_adjcartalert' doesn't exist
        [string:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 42S02
        [file:protected] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
        [line:protected] => 228
        [trace:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
                        [line] => 228
                        [function] => execute
                        [class] => PDOStatement
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 110
                        [function] => _execute
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                        [line] => 300
                        [function] => _execute
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
                        [line] => 479
                        [function] => execute
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Statement
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
                        [line] => 238
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed`
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 419
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed`
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 340
                        [function] => query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed`
                            )

                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 608
                        [function] => raw_query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed`
                            )

                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                        [line] => 590
                        [function] => multi_query
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed` ;
    UPDATE mage_adjcartalert SET `status` = 'pending';

    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `abandoned_at` DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER `status` ;

    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert_history (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `sent_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `txt` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


                            )

                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 933
                        [function] => multiQuery
                        [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed` ;
    UPDATE mage_adjcartalert SET `status` = 'pending';

    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `abandoned_at` DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER `status` ;

    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert_history (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `sent_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `txt` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


                            )

                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Cartalert/sql/adjcartalert_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                        [line] => 30
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `status` ENUM( 'pending', 'invalid' ) DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL AFTER `is_preprocessed` ;
    UPDATE mage_adjcartalert SET `status` = 'pending';

    ALTER TABLE mage_adjcartalert ADD `abandoned_at` DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER `status` ;

    CREATE TABLE mage_adjcartalert_history (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `sent_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `customer_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `customer_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `txt` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


                            )

                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 624
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Cartalert/sql/adjcartalert_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                            )

                        [function] => include
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 437
                        [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => upgrade
                                [1] => 0.1.0
                                [2] => 3.2.0
                            )

                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 320
                        [function] => _upgradeResourceDb
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 0.1.0
                                [1] => 3.2.0
                            )

                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                        [line] => 235
                        [function] => applyUpdates
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [15] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                        [line] => 417
                        [function] => applyAllUpdates
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                        [type] => ::
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                        [line] => 343
                        [function] => _initModules
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/app/Mage.php
                        [line] => 683
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                        [type] => ->
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [scope_code] => 
                                        [scope_type] => store
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [file] => /home/vetement/public_html/index.php
                        [line] => 87
                        [function] => run
                        [class] => Mage
                        [type] => ::
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => store
                            )

                    )

            )

        [errorInfo] => Array
            (
                [0] => 42S02
                [1] => 1146
                [2] => Table 'vetement_mage2.mage_adjcartalert' doesn't exist
            )

    )
```

Comment: I see there is a line "-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mage_adjcartalert;" which should drop the table before trying to recreate it - but that line starts with a comment, so it doesn't run. That's strange.

Comment: I just dropped the table mage_adjcartalert. Then I refreshed, and reloaded the website. Had another table to drop. mage_adjcartalert_history. Then reloaded again. Still have the same error. Will post what I get below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the version number of this extension have changed and Magento tries to run the sql code associated to the new version, but some table already exists.

You can remove all table from the current version and run again the update script (by just accessing front or back). Or check if things are missing, put them manually, and update the core_resource table to reflect the new version.

The version of your extension module could be found in its config.xml file.

To check what is being run to update version, look at the sql folder of your extension module.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping only table doesnt help you.. U have to clear a row related to that table in core_resource table also. This is the table that stores the version number of the table scripts. As per the above comments,in ur case u have dropped only "mage_adjcartalert" table but u didnt clear the row in "core_resouce" table. So in core_resource table, search for "adjcartalert_setup" value and delete that row. Now run ur store.. NOTE: Take db backup for ur future sake...